# Mapping image from drone in QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Is it possible to map a drone image JPEG directly over a QGIS project as a layer or is it necessary to make some post processing, because it's not rendered on it's correct position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, there is a QGIS plugin named Vertical Photo Placer that can exploit the metadata  to place vertical drone photos on map [github link](https://github.com/verticalphotoplacer/VerticalPhotoPlacer).

Comment: Testing, seems promising, thanks. By the way requires exiftool http://exiftool.sourceforge.net/install.html#Unix

Answer (score 3):

No, QGIS cannot exploit the image location, elevation,pitch, roll, and yaw to automatically georeference your images.  You can manually georeference individual drone image yourself using QGIS.  [See this tutorial on georeferencing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html).  If you have a series of drone images with sufficient overlap you can use applications like Open Drone Map (FOSS4G) , Agisoft Metashape (free trial), or online options like Drone Deploy or Pix4d (both with free trial periods).  These Structure from Motion (SfM) applications will merge all of the overlapping images together producing a single orthomosaic file and a surface model.

Comment: +helpful video on drone mosaic georeferencing in QGIS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUgpBRajuTg